# Replicating directory structure in Gulp dest

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to optimize images in a couple of different locations using Gulp. This is the directory structure:

```
|-- app
   |-- _images
       -- image1.jpg
       -- image2.jpg
   |-- _templates
      |-- _pages
         |--_services
            |--_images
               -- image1.jpg
               -- image2.jpg
```

And this is the code

```
gulp.task('images:tmp', function() {
return gulp.src(['app/templates/pages/**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}', 'app/images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}'], {base: 'app/'})
// Caching images that ran through imagemin
.pipe(cache(imagemin({
  interlaced: true,
})))
.pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the app's "templates" and "pages" directories are copied into the root of ".tmp," along with the "services" directory:

```
|-- .tmp
   |-- _images
       -- image1.jpg
       -- image2.jpg
   |-- _templates
      |-- _pages
         |--_services
            |--_images
               -- image1.jpg
               -- image2.jpg
```

I only want the "services" directory in the root, like so:

```
|-- .tmp
   |-- _images
       -- image1.jpg
       -- image2.jpg
   |-- _services
       |--_images
          -- image1.jpg
          -- image2.jpg
```

How do I write the task to replicate the directory structure above? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot add this as a comment)

Split your source stream in two streams and return merged stream as per the recipe at https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md :

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');
gulp.task('images:tmp', function() {
  var stream1 = gulp.src('app/templates/pages/**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}')
                  .pipe(cache(imagemin({interlaced: true})))
                  .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
                );  
  var stream1 = gulp.src('app/images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}',{base: 'app/'})
                  .pipe(cache(imagemin({interlaced: true})))
                  .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
                ); 
  return merge(stream1,stream2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, maoizm. This worked for me after editing the second "var stream1" to read "var stream2" and removing the apparently superfluous ); from the streams.

```
gulp.task('images:tmp', function() {
  var stream1 = gulp.src('app/templates/pages/**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}')
              .pipe(cache(imagemin({interlaced: true})))
              .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'));            
  var stream2 = gulp.src('app/images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}',{base: 'app/'})
              .pipe(cache(imagemin({interlaced: true})))
              .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'));            
  return merge(stream1,stream2);
});
```